# Add constant value to vector (or other data structure) in N(1)?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to figure out a problem. I have a vector with elements:
`1, 2, 3, 4`

and I am wondering if it is possible to increase (all or some) values at once in O(1) complexity.

for example I might want to add 3 so I have:
`4, 5, 6, 7`.

Is it even possible? Maybe you can give me other insight how to approach this problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You will need to alter some fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe, first, before you can do this in `O(1)`. So, I would suggest starting on that task, first. Perhaps al alternative approach is also possible using quantum computing, but that's not my area of specialty.

Comment: yeah, srry. I mean O(1) .. O(N) solution would be going through all elements in vector and increase them.

Comment: There is no such solution. I suggest you study a bit more about the big O notation, and maybe a bit of computer architecture. The fastest you will get is by using SIMD instructions. Most popular libraries like Eigen use them to perform vectorized operations on multiple numbers at once. These vary based on the CPU, given the size of the special registers that support such operations.

Comment: Ok, just store the added number next to the vector? And every time someone asks for an element, add the number to it on the fly?

Comment: Since adding a constant value to a single slot doesn't interfere with other slots, you could parallelize the activity, or do some loop unrolling.  Some processors may perform multiple adds very efficiently.  Load up many registers, add the value to the registers, store the registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean O(1), then yes, it's possible.

1, 2, 3, 4 are just human conditional notations/symbols of volumes one, two, three, four. You can define the symbol 1 is four, 2 is five... Do you understand what I am getting at?

You can implement your own vector class, and override the constant vector's subscript operator for interpreting real values differently:

```
int operator[](size_t idx) const {
  return v_[idx] + 3;  // v_ is an encapsulated std::vector
}

// Or like below, but inheriting std containers is not considered
// a good practice.
int operator[](size_t idx) const {
  return std::vector<int>::operator[](idx) + 3;
}
```

So, you fill your vector with the values 1, 2, 3, 4 and read the values 4, 5, 6, 7 from a const vector reference.

Comment: Yes, I do mean O(1), already edited the description. Thanks for reply :)